# Ошибка Privileged Instruction (EPrivilege)

Tags: delphi

Имеется тип `tbgra = record`, с 4-мя полями типа `byte`. Ещё есть динамический массив типа `tbgra`. Также имеется тип `pbgra1darray`, являющийся указателем на массив типа `tbgra`. Вот код:

```
    program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses  SysUtils;

type tbgra = record
     b,g,r,a:byte;
     end;

     bgra1darray  = array [1..3000*3000] of tbgra;
     pbgra1darray = ^bgra1darray;

var pa: pbgra1darray;
    a : array of tbgra;
///////////////////////
procedure bps(a:pbgra1darray; l:integer);
var x:integer;
begin

for x := 1 to l do
  begin
    a^[x].b:=77;
    if x mod 10 =0 then
      begin
        write (a^[x].b);
        write(' ');
        writeln(x);
      end;
  end;

end;

begin

setlength(a, 10001);
bps(@a,10000);        //Privileged Instruction (EPrivilege), х=1480

readln;
end.
```

Что же я делаю не так? Задача стоит написать процедуру, обрабатывающую массив по переданному ей указателю. Причём длина массива может измениться.

Comment: delphi не знаю, поэтому только предположение.

У Вас массив размером 3000\*3000\*4 (как минимум) т.е. примерно 36мегабайт в стеке. Слишком много. Надо динамически выделять в куче. В С++ new, в C malloc(). В delphi не знаю, но что-то есть.

Comment: @avp, А какая разница: объявлять массив обычным способом или выделять под него место в куче? (Хотя bgra1darray - это тип, он ничего не занимает. А pa - указатель на этот массив - 4 байта)

Comment: @ололо, дело в том, что в windows обычно стеке доступно (если память не изменяет) 2 МБ.

Comment: @avp, кабы дельфи размещала массивы в стеке целиком, нельзя было бы создать массив размером 1Гб )

Comment: @Nofate, Дык я не понял, bps(a,10000) передаёт в процедуру массив или указатель нанего? Почему? Что это за Делфовские заморочки? Насколько я знаю @a- указатель на массив, а a-сам массив. Разве нет?

Comment: @Nofate, написал bps(a,10000), пишет "Incompitable types: pbgra1darray and Dynamic array". И если я напишу bps(a,10000), то в процедуре будет обрабатыватся именно переменная a, или a скопируется в процедуру и обработается там?

Comment: Важно быстродействие, а насколько я знаю, если передавать в процедуры большие переменные, то это снижает производительность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[[[@a](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)vp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), `SetLength(...)` как раз работает с кучей.

[[@ололо](/users/4501/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE)](/users/4501/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE), а вам таки обязательно передавать явно указатель на массив в процедуру? В таком виде неплохо работает:

```
var a : bgra1darray;

procedure bps(a:bgra1darray; l:integer);
var x:integer;
begin
  for x := 1 to l do
  begin
    a[x].b:=77;
    if x mod 10 =0 then
    begin
      write (a[x].b);
      write(' ');
      writeln(x);
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  setlength(a, 10001);
  bps(a,10000);
  readln;
end.
```

UPD0.  Да, мне пришлось изменить определение:

```
bgra1darray  = array of tbgra;
```

UPD1. Когда вы передаете массив в процедуру, разумеется он не будет скопирован. В этом легко убедиться, посмотрев соответствующий ассемблерный код:

```
Project1.dpr.38: bps(a,10000);        //Privileged Instruction (EPrivilege), х=1480
0040B1B2 BA10270000       mov edx,$00002710
0040B1B7 A13C1E4100       mov eax,[$00411e3c]
0040B1BC E8FBDDFFFF       call bps
```

И в самой процедуре:

```
Project1.dpr.19: begin
00408FBC 55               push ebp
00408FBD 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
00408FBF 51               push ecx
00408FC0 53               push ebx
00408FC1 56               push esi
00408FC2 57               push edi
00408FC3 8BDA             mov ebx,edx
00408FC5 8945FC           mov [ebp-$04],eax
00408FC8 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
00408FCB E89CC6FFFF       call @DynArrayAddRef
```

Как видим, просто передается адрес динамического массива (через `eax`), а потом помещается в стек (`mov [ebp-$04],eax`).

Очевидно вы натыкались на эксепшен, потому что передавали в процедуру адрес динамического массива `bps(@a, 10000)`,  что приводило к двойному взятию указателя и вы просто влезали в чужую память в итоге.

Comment: Я тоже смотрел этот ассемблерный код, но мало что понимал.  Спасибо за подробный ответ

Comment: Ну, теперь-то понятно стало? Могу что-то еще дообъяснить, если есть неясности.

Comment: Кстати, многие не знают тот ффкт, что динамические массивы в Delphi имеют встроенный счетчик ссылок. Поэтому для освобождения массива достаточно, в принципе, сделать `a := nil;`.

Answer (score -1):

Вот этот вариант меня больше удовлтворяет

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses  SysUtils;

type tbgra = record
     b,g,r,a:byte;
     end;

     bgra1darray  = array of tbgra;   <----------------------
     pbgra1darray = ^bgra1darray;

var pa: pbgra1darray;
    a : array of tbgra;
///////////////////////
procedure bps(a:pbgra1darray; l:integer);
var x:integer;
begin

for x := 1 to l do
  begin
    a^[x].b:=77;
    if x mod 10 =0 then
      begin
        write (a^[x].b);
        write(' ');
        writeln(x);
      end;
  end;

end;

begin

setlength(a, 10001);
bps(@a,10000);

writeln('done!');
writeln(a[432].b);

readln;
end.
```

А почему появлялась эта ошибка для меня лично осталось загадкой, впрочем и что она значит я тоже не понял. Буду рад если кто объяснит.

Comment: Обновил пост

Comment: Опять же у вас лишнее взятие указателя, на этот раз без ошибки, но все равно не дающее никаких преимуществ по сравнению с моим вариантом. Напротив, это добавит лишнюю операцию при передаче параметра и еще одно в процедуре для разыменовывания указателя.